# vue.js v-for iterate variable number of times

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I would like to iterate rows in a table based over a range. But all examples I've seen show how to do this for a constant for example,

```
<div>
  <span v-for="n in 10">{{ n }} </span>
</di
```

How can I do this for a variable similar to this,

```
<table>
   <tr v-for="(el, index) in form.repeat" :key="index">
      <td>hello</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This variable form.repeat is set in a form on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue week, my workaround for it was setting a variable in your data section to the number of rows you want. In my case based on the number of devices my backend returned the length of the list as part of the response. When Vue receives this response. I assign the variable that I created earlier in my data section to this number and I plug that into my v-for loop.

[image]

In the data section:

```
data: () => ({'num_pis': 0})
```

In the template part, reference the number. This is just a snippet, I'm using a v-data-table from Vuetify.

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <td class="table-content-style">{{ props.item.metric_name }}</td>
  <td v-for="i in num_pis">
    {{ props.item[i] }}
  </td>
</template>
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEmZgX)

Comment: and thanks for this reply. I know little about Vuetify and v-data-table but it seems I need to have the repeating variable in my data. In my case the 'form' is an element in which this table is an iteration. Thanks for this, I'll play with that

Comment: I now have an iteration on an array called 'reps' if reaps = [1,12,1000] it will iterate once, twice and four times, in other words the number of characters in each number and once, twelve times and one thousands times as I'd like. How do i get it to read each number instead of seeing each number as an element in an array? thanks

Comment: Previously when i was using form.repeat with quotes around it, 'form.repeat' is was iterating 11 times, which is the number of characters in form.repeat. But when I use handlebars to see what form.repeat is it will render as an integer. {{form.repeat}} renders as for example 3. Why is form.repeat not being read as a value? Thanks